# Angular 7.2.15, accessing RestoredState data after Navigation (popstate) because of a Back navigation

Tags: angular, navigation, angular-ui-router

I want to achieve a navigation between a Search Form, an Item Details Form and back to the first Search Form (implementing a browse back functionality).
I'm trying to save the state of the Search Form (search criteria inserted by the user) to navigate to the Item Details and finally to go to the previous page restoring the data inserted by the user initially.
I expected to use the Angular native router capability to send data to the next Form and to get the restoredState once back to the previous page (Angular 7.2.10 feature).

I successfully was able to send data to the next Form, using the Angular 7.2.10 navigate State feature, but I'm not able to get the restored State once back because I don't know where to take the data.
I noticed that in the router Object I can se in 'transitions' the restoredState property containing the correct navigationId and my custom object previously saved, but I don't know how to access it.

The navigation between Forms uses Angular Router capability like:

this.router.navigate('...', { relativeTo: this.activatedRoute, state: {state: state} });

Using the state to send data to the next Form. This is working.
Before navigating I'm saving the current State (Search Form state) with some code like:

window.history.pushState({navigationId: window.history.state.navigationId, custom: state}, "");

to save the current state.
In the next form I can access the state saved by the navigate call, but once back executed with the Location service I don't know how to take the original data:

this.location.back();

I expect to get the restoredState somewhere in the router service once the destination form is reached.